# Why does my regex with word boundary fail?

Tags: python, regex, word-boundary

I'd like to match number, positive or negative, possibly with currency sign in front. But I don't want something like PSM-9. My code is:

```
test='AAA PCSK-9, $111 -3,33'
re.findall(r'\b-?[$€£]?-?\d+[\d,.]*\b', test)
```

Output is:`['-9', '111', '3,33']`
Could someone explain why -9 is matched? Thank you in advance.

Edit:
I don't any part of PCSK-9 is matched it is like a name of a product rather a number. So my desired output is:

```
['111', '3,33']
```

Comment: Can u please add your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is `['111', '3,33']`. Basically, I want to count the numbers but PSK-9 is not what I want because it's more like a name of a product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) matches between the K and the dash. The 2 parts after the dash `[$€£]?-?` are optional because of the questionmark and then you match one or more times a digit. This results in the match `-9`

What you might use instead of a word boundary is an assertion that checks if what is before and after the match is not a non whitespace character `\S` using a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead.

`(?<!\S)-?[$€£]?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)(?!\S)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RKI7Y4/1) | [Python demo](http://rextester.com/IOI10033)

Comment: Thank you, the 4th bird, `\S` perfectly solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `\b` matches the gap between `K` and `-`, a word and a non-word character. If you want to avoid matching `-` if it's preceded by a word you can use negative lookbehind instead:

```
re.findall(r'[$€£]?(?:(?<!\w)-)?\d+[\d,.]*\b', test)
```

With your sample input, this returns:

```
['9', '111', '3,33']
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/A66C5W/1

Comment: Thank you, blhsing. I forgot to put my expected output, which is `['111', '3,33']`. Basically, I want to count the numbers but PSK-9 is not what I want because it's more like a name of some product like BMW X5.

Answer (score 0):

`-9` is matched because `-`  is a non-word character, and `S` is a word character... so in between there's an interword boundary `\b`, as you state in your regexp.